# Do I need to elimate extra calls to `glUseProgram()`?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Say I have a bit of code that calls `glUseProgram(programId)` at different points, but sometimes ends up calling `glUseProgram(1)` twice, with the same argument (ie program1 is asked for twice).

Should I eliminate the spurious calls to `glUseProgram` or does `glUseProgram` already perform that check internally?

Comment: The short and useless answer is "it depends on the OpenGL implementation". I hope someone will have a better answer. It might also help to specify your target platform.

Comment: I'm targetting iOS right now

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESApplicationDesign/OpenGLESApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH6-SW6) you should prevent redundant calls for `glEnable` state changes. So an assumption could be made that the same applies to the `glUseProgram`. Even if this assumption is incorrect, it is still a good idea to order your drawing calls by program and uniform setting if possible.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, if I use `gluseprogram(PROGRAMID)` with the same ID twice, without setting to something else in between, the display driver crashes. So I wouldn't.

(edit) Sorry, that was not true. It was actually something to do with the SFML windowing environment.  Had wrong settings so was closing the window (and thus the OpenGL environment) before the OpenGL functions were able to 'clean house'.